# Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ab=2$. Find the max value of $\frac{3}{2\left(a+b\right)^2}$ and $a, b$ where max is attained, without calculus.

Tags: inequality, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

My thinking:

By Arithmetic and Geometric mean inequality (AGM):

$ab\le \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$

We know $ab=2$

$\rightarrow$  $2\le \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$

$\rightarrow$ $2\le \frac{a^2+b^2}{4}$

$\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{2}\le \:\frac{1}{\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}}$

$\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{2}\le \:\frac{4}{a^2+b^2}$

$\rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{a^2+b^2}\right)\le \:\frac{4}{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{3}{a^2+b^2}\right)$

$\rightarrow$ $\frac{3}{2\left(a+b\right)^2}\le \frac{12}{\left(a+b\right)^4}$

**Therefore the max value is $\frac{12}{\left(a+b\right)^4}$**

Maximum value is attained when $a=b$:

So we can write:

$\rightarrow$ $\frac{3}{2\left(a\right)^2}=\frac{12}{\left(a\right)^4}$

$\rightarrow$ $3a^4=24a^2$

$\rightarrow$ **$a=0, -2\sqrt{2},+2\sqrt{2}$**

**Therefore the max value of $a,b$ are $0,-2\sqrt{2},+2\sqrt{2}$**

I'm not completely sure about my answer, if anyone could provide some feedback, that would be amazing! Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

$ab\le \frac{\left(a+b\right)^2}{2}\:\rightarrow \:2\le \frac{\left(a+b\right)^2}{4}\:\rightarrow \:\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{\left(a+b\right)^2}{16}\:\rightarrow \:\frac{3}{2\left(a+b\right)^2}\le \:\frac{3}{16}$

Comment: $(a + b)^2  \ne a^2  + b^2$, $(a + b)^2  = a^2  + 2ab + b^2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream.

Comment: Note that AM-GM requires you to assume $a,b \geq 0$.  This is actually sufficient to find the maximum, but in a proof you should show why you may reduce to this case.

Comment: @Yaya123 Note your second line is $2\le \frac{a^2+b^2}{4}$ while your third is $\frac{1}{2}\le \:\frac{1}{\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}}$. However, with both positive (or negative) values, when taking reciprocals of both sides in an inequality, the inequality direction changes. For example, by dividing both sides by $ab$, we get $a \le b \; \to \; \frac{1}{b} \le \frac{1}{a} \; \to \; \frac{1}{a} \ge \frac{1}{b}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you found the maximal value of $a, b$? The question is asking $\frac3{2(a+b)^2}$!

Using AM-GM is, yes, the best approach. Here is my answer.

Since using AM-GM, $8=4ab\le(a+b)^2$, so $\frac1{(a+b)^2}\le\frac18$.

So the maxima of $\frac3{2(a+b)^2}$ is $\frac32\cdot\frac18=\frac3{16}$ when $a=b=\pm\sqrt2$.

Comment: Hey I found another way to do it without AGM, would this be valid: $ab\le \frac{\left(a+b\right)^2}{2}\:\rightarrow \:2\le \frac{\left(a+b\right)^2}{4}\:\rightarrow \:\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{\left(a+b\right)^2}{16}\:\rightarrow \:\frac{3}{2\left(a+b\right)^2}\le \:\frac{3}{16}$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the given restriction into the proposed expression.

Then your problem reduces to study a single-variable real-valued function:
\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{2(a + b)^{2}} & = \frac{3}{2\left(a + \dfrac{2}{a}\right)^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{3a^{2}}{2(a^{2} + 2)^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{a}{a^{2} + 2}\right)^{2}
\end{align*}

Since the quadratic function is increasing, it suffices to study when the argument attains its max.

More precisely, according to the AM-GM inequality, we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
a^{2} + 2 \geq 2\sqrt{2a^{2}} = 2\sqrt{2}|a| \Longleftrightarrow \left|\frac{a}{a^{2} + 2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}

Hence the maximum value attained is given by:
\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{2(a + b)^{2}} \leq \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2} = \frac{3}{16}
\end{align*}

In order to determine $a$ which corresponds to the maximum, you can solve the equation:
\begin{align*}
a^{2} - 2\sqrt{2}|a| + 2 = 0
\end{align*}

Once you know $a$, you also know $b$ and you are done.

Hopefully this helps !